# how to view a list of txt file in a folder?

Tags: linux, shell

I would like to have only txt file in a folder. i tried `cd folder` then `ls *.txt`. 
I have the good result. but now i would like to have the result using only one linux command. 
I tried  `ls *.txt folder`  and  `cd folder| ls   *.txt`.
 how to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ls folder/*.txt
```

or

```
cd folder; ls *.txt
```

Comment: as to the second option - better use: pushd folder; ls *.txt; popd

Comment: or `cd folder; ls *.txt; cd -`. or `find folder -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' -printf '%f\n'` -- better when used in scripts. or just `echo folder/*.txt`

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
ls folder/*.txt
```

Comment: lists file in "folder" that is in root directory.

Comment: Uhms, it was a typo, please do not downvote for these things @loentar

Answer (score 1):

`ls folder/*.txt` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use grep too :

```
 ls -l folder/ | grep '\.txt'$
```

Comment: Please review, I do not think it will do what's required.

Comment: Edited again - as dot is a special character, it has to be escaped in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You must cd to the folder first, then just ls *.txt